Since which day all new orgs have Lightning experience only for non-admin users?
We have faced an issue that non-admin users on our customer org were not able to switch to Classic even though we as admins we able to.
We have seen articles that users switching from Essential edition may face this issue
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383078&type=1 also a suggestion to open a Case if we need to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=xcloud.overview_edition_lex_only.htm&type=5
However, my client org was never an Essential edition but rather it started as E1E or Unlimited edition.
Does that mean that all new orgs have Lightning experience only for non-admin users? When this started?

We have opened a SF Support to enable Classic for non-admin users and got the following information about the switch date

This critical update ( 'Turn on Lightning Experience' critical update
) started activating on a rolling basis on January 7, 2020
For more information please refer to the below help article:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383316&type=1

